# Digital clock -

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to display a digital clock.Here is what i have to display the time in a textblock which is in 24 hour format that i dont know how to convert to 12 hours.

```
DispatcherTimer timerdigital;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //StartTimer(null, null);

        timerdigital = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerdigital.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
        timerdigital.Start();
        timerdigital.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a)
        {
            tbDigital.Text = "" + DateTime.Now.Hour + ":"
          + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":"
          + DateTime.Now.Second;


        });
```

thank you

Comment: A consideration (perhaps minor, perhaps not, depending on your app's intended audience): 8-segment displays will only make sense in cultures that use Arabic numerals. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/25/4036123.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the digital-like display, but for switching to 12-hour clock from 24-hour the easiest approach would be to use DateTime string formatting:

```
timerdigital.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a)
        {
            tbDigital.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
        });
```

Here `hh` is the hours in 12-hour format, `mm` is minutes, `ss` is seconds, and `tt` is the AM/PM marker.

See more about Date and Time format strings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice ready to use source code for wpf:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/digitalclock.aspx
About the 12/24 hour format:

```
 int smallhour = (Hour > 12) ? Hour - 12 : Hour;
```